# Decoding UART over IR

Tags: uart, infrared

I have a system transmitting UART (38400) over IR with a carrier frequency of 425khz.

How do I take a receiver led and feed this into a microcontroller. Obviously I can't just put it through an op amp and connect to the UART RX on the microcontroller because I need to remove/demodulate from the carrier frequency first.

What techniques can I use to do this?

Comment: You can use a PLL (phase locked loop) based circuit.

Answer (score 1):

Generally you can buy IR receivers that integrate the detector, bandpass filter, and amplifier all in one, with a variety of different bandpass filters for different carrier frequencies. The output of which could be fed directly into the UART RX.